# How do you calculate the energy transfer of sound to a certain area?

Tags: energy, acoustics

So imagine if you measure the sound intensity at a certain spot to be $ 72$ deciBels. If you look at the SI-units used in the ratio these are $ \text{W/m}^2$. Does this mean that you can calculate the exact energy transfer per second on a given area, e.g. 2 cm2 to just be the amount of decibells you measure times the area including with the relative intensity?

I would like to calculate the energy transfer of sound.

Answer (score 1):

The decibel (dB) is a unit for expressing the **ratio** between two sound intensities and so has no units.

One decibel equals $10 \log_{10} \left (\dfrac{I_1}{I_2}\right )=20\log_{10} \left (\dfrac{P_1}{P_2}\right )$, where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are the intensity of the two sounds and $P_1$ and $P_2$ are the corresponding amplitudes of the pressure waves.

[Examples of sound pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_pressure#Examples_of_sound_pressure) is a table which illustrates the use of the auditory threshold at $1\,\rm kHz$ as the reference of $0\,\rm dB$ used on many instruments.

You may also find the Wikipedia article [Sound Power](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sound_power) of interest.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up. I changed my post. If you use as a reference intensity just atmospheric pressure, how do you calculate the energy exactly? I look at the page but I can't seem to correctly figure it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: @bananenheld It is impossible for a sound wave to have a **amplitude** equal to atmospheric pressure. Note that a sound wave can be thought of as a variation in pressure about atmospheric pressure.

Comment: Ok thank you for clearing that mistake up. How can you calculate the energy then?

Comment: [Sound Intensity and Sound Level](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/17-3-sound-intensity-and-sound-level/)

Comment: I cannot figure out with the link how to compute the energy given the decibel. You use the $ I_0 $ and the decibel formula?

Comment: Looking at the "Sound Intensity and Sound Level" table you will see that the reference power per square metre, $10^{-12}$, is 0 dB.  So 72 dB is a power per square metre of $10^{72/10} \times 10^{-12} \approx 1.6 \times 10^{-5}$